# Radius of convergence for unusual power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the following infinite series:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}x^{n^2}$$

I need to determine the radius of convergence. So, what troubles me is the $x^{n^2}$ as for a normal $x^n$ I already determined the radius to be $1$. Now, I interpreted the higher exponent as just considering the standard power series, which skips some exponents by coefficients of $0$. This should most certainly not affect the convergence of the series and also not the limit of the coefficients.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172637/what-is-the-radius-of-convergence-of-displaystyle-sum-n-0-inftyzn2 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839670/whats-the-series-and-whats-the-radius-of-convergence-of-this-power-series – the same arguments can be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x|\geqslant1$, then it is not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}x^{n^2}=0$ and therefore the series diverges.

If $|x|<1$, then$$\left|\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}x^{n^2}\right|<\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}|x|^n$$and you already know that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}|x|^n$ converges. Therefore, the original series converges too.

So, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on the answer of José: you can write

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}x^{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\;,\;\;\text{with}$$

$$c_n=\left\{\frac12,\,\frac23,\,0,0,\frac45,\,0,0,0,0,\,\frac89,0,\ldots\right\}= \begin{cases}\cfrac{2^{\sqrt n}}{2^{\sqrt n}+1},&n\;\text{is a perfect square}\\{}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Thus, to find its convergence radius you can *now* apply Cauchy-Hadamard:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{2^{\sqrt n}+1}=1$$